# A metric space with a countable dense subset removed is totally disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am wondering if it is true, and what the proof would go like, that given a metric space $X$ with a countable dense subset $D$, $\ X\setminus D$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: But $\Bbb R$ with **any** dense subset removed will be totally disconnected.

Answer (score 9):

This is not true. $\mathbb Q^2\subset\mathbb R^2$ is dense, but in fact $\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb Q^2$ is path connected.

Comment: What if X contains exactly two non-cut points?

Comment: What do you mean, non-cut points?